# how to access string member of struct that is dynamically allocated with double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, double

I'm able to access the double pointer structure part that has a member of type integer, but I can't access the member that is of type string

I get a segmentation error when trying to print out the commented out part, so I commented that out.

thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BLOCK 2
#define LINESIZE 1024
#define NLINES 1000
#define NAMESIZE 20


typedef struct{
    char last[NAMESIZE];
    char first[NAMESIZE];
}name;

typedef struct{
    name name;
    int score;
}record;

typedef struct{
    record *data;
    size_t nalloc;
    size_t nused;
}record_list;

int main(void){


record **lines, **p;
char buffer[LINESIZE];
size_t i, j, nalloc, nused;

nalloc = nused = 0;
lines =0;

while(fgets(buffer, LINESIZE, stdin)){
    if(nused == nalloc){
    p = realloc(lines, (nalloc + BLOCK) * sizeof(record*));

    if(p==0){
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed\n");
        break;
    }
    lines = p;
    nalloc +=BLOCK;
    }
    lines[nused] = malloc(sizeof(record));

    if(lines[nused] == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        break;
    }
    lines[nused++]->score = 50+nused;
    /* strcpy(lines[nused++]->name.first,"hello");
    strcpy(lines[nused++]->name.last,"last"); */

}

for(i = 0; i < nused; i++)
    printf("%d ", lines[i]->score);

for(i = 0; i < nused; i++)
    printf("%s ", lines[i]->name.first);

}
```

Also the last output doesn't printout anything to output?
output:

```
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65
```

Comment: Quick tip I noticed before actually reading through, you're declaring null pointers with a 0, this will probably end up in the compiler giving warnings and no compiler protection. Instead declare them with NULL(you must include the stdlib), also and most importantly it adds A LOT of clarity to the code Ex: lines =NULL;

Answer (score 0):

```
lines[nused++]->score = 50+nused;
/* strcpy(lines[nused++]->name.first,"hello");
strcpy(lines[nused++]->name.last,"last"); */
```

The problem in the commented out lines of code is that `nused` is being incorrectly incremented each line. `nused` (before any increment) is the last index which references an allocated buffer. So `nused` should only be incremented *after* it has been used for all the array accesses.

```
lines[nused]->score = 50+nused;
strcpy(lines[nused]->name.first,"hello");
strcpy(lines[nused]->name.last,"last");
nused++;
```